# How to create @Entity class by using room with Map<>

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room, entity

How to create @Entity class by using room with Map<>

I have such data class:

```
data class ListResponse(
    @SerializedName("answer")
    val answer: Map<Int, ItemList>
)
 
data class ItemList(
    @SerializedName("yes")
    val yes: YesItem,
 
    @SerializedName("no")
    val no: NoItem
)
 
data class YesItem(
    @SerializedName("time")
    val timeYes: String,
 
    @SerializedName("date")
    val dateYes: String
)
 
data class NoItem(
    @SerializedName("time")
    val timeNo: String,
 
    @SerializedName("date")
    val dateNo: String
)
```

and I need data base with such strucure:
Primary key must be taken as Int key from Map

Map Int key|timeYes|dateYes|timeNo|dateNo

something like that:

```
@Entity(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
data class PromotionListEntity(
    @PrimaryKey 
    @SerializedName("id") // I don't know SerializedName for Int value
    val id:  //answer Map Int key

    @SerializedName("timeYes")
    val timeYes: String,

    @SerializedName("dateYes")
    val dateYes: String,

    @SerializedName("timeNo")
    val timeNo: String,

    @SerializedName("dateNo")
    val dateNo: String,


){
    companion object{
        const val TABLE_NAME = "answer_table"
    }
}
```

Comment: Room is still SQL under the hood and SQL doesn't allow you to store maps/lists structures without serialization first. I think the solution to your problem is having ForeignKeys that will link those entities together. ListResponse can stay the way it is but it can be only used as an output of SQL query

Comment: but with TypeConverters?

Comment: Yes. That is the serialization I meant. I think you can just write TypeCoverters for the final entity you want `PromotionListEntity` and not bother with any further SQL relations but how those data relate to each other will depend on your needs.