# Room database many to many on same table StackOverflowError

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

I have a table of products. Each product can contain a list of other "spare parts" products. Each product also contains a user manual, which is stored in the attachments table.

Product entity:

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "products", foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = AttachmentEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["attachment_id"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
    ]
)
data class ProductEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "attachment_id")
    val attachmentId: Int,
)
```

Attachment entity

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "attachment"
)
data class AttachmentEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int
)
```

Cross ref table

```kotlin
@Entity(
    tableName = "products_products",
    primaryKeys = ["product_id1", "product_id2"],
    foreignKeys = [
        ForeignKey(
            entity = ProductEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["product_id1"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
        ForeignKey(
            entity = ProductEntity::class,
            parentColumns = ["id"],
            childColumns = ["product_id2"],
            onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        ),
    ]
)
data class ProductProductCrossRef(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id1")
    val productId1: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "product_id2")
    val productId2: Int,
)
```

POJO class for product

```kotlin
data class PopulatedProduct(
    @Embedded
    val entity: ProductEntity,

    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "attachment_id",
        entityColumn = "id"
    )
    val userManual: AttachmentEntity?,

    @Relation(
        entity = ProductEntity::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "id",
        associateBy = Junction(
            value = ProductProductCrossRef::class,
            parentColumn = "product_id1",
            entityColumn = "product_id2",
        )
    )
    val spareparts: List<PopulatedProduct> <--- StackOverflowError 
)
```

I get `java.lang.StackOverflowError` on build.

If I replace `PopulatedProduct` with `ProductEntity`, I can build the project. However I want `PopulatedProduct` in order to get the user manuals associated with the product.

Answer (score 0):

The StackOverflow is because your are basically saying getmyself from myself which thus is getting myself and thus getting myself .... (forever aka stack overflow)

What you tried, i.e. using `val spareparts List<ProductEntity>` is the correct way.

You then use something like:-

```
@Transaction
@Query("SELECT * FROM products_products .... ")
fun getPopulatedProducts(): List<PopulatedProduct>
```

Comment: sorry for disturbing you, but can you help me with my task?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74717292/how-to-create-entity-class-by-using-room-with-map